# Why does the value go out of index of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, bubble-sort

In bubble sort, when first iteration of the inner for loop takes place, value of `i` is `0`, so the loop will run till `j` is less than `n`, but when `j` becomes equal to `n-1`, and we do `a[j+1]` for another time.
why doesn't this value go out of index of the array and the code executes properly?

```
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n-i;j++) {        /* When i=0 & j<n why doesn't  */
            if(a[j] > a[j+1]) {     /* a[j+1] go out of index when */
                temp=a[j+1];        /* value of j is n-1           */
                a[j+1]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: lets say it does. How would you know it? it's UB

Comment: `j<n-i` should be `j<n-i-1`

Comment: Assuming `a` has `n` elements, then I would say this *does* index out of bounds.  You may simply have gotten "lucky" and not encountered any visible problems (so far), but it certainly looks buggy.

Comment: To make it go out of bounds, change it to `j<n-i-1`

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a proper , Tested Bubble Sort function:

```
void bubble_sort(long a[], long n)
{
  long i, j, t;

  for (i = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); i++)
  {
    for (j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++)
    {
      if (a[j] > a[j+1])
      {
        t         = a[j];
        a[j]   = a[j+1];
        a[j+1] = t;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with you second for's, second argument. 
It should run till `j` is less than `i`, not `n`.

```
void bubble(double *t, int db) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = db-1; i > 0; --i)
        for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            if (t[j+1] < t[j]) {
                double temp = t[j];
                t[j] = t[j+1];
                t[j+1] = temp;
            }
}
```

Comment: i am not asking for a solution, i just want to know why doesn't a[j+1] go out of index in the second loop